# Node Command Line Tool with NVM bash:not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I am writing a simple node CLI tool and having trouble using with NVM. Even installed node locally and use `nvm use system` and the CLI file still cannot be found.  Code is simply including the shell designation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("Hello, here is my first CLI tool")
```

When running this from command line I get this:
`-bash: cli-project: command not found`

Have tried everything. Node is at /usr/local/bin/node, and have even added that. Have used system location of node. Have added the path to /etc/paths. Nothing works!  Does anyone have experience building a node CLI tool using NVM how to set up initially?  NVM is set up correctly on my machine, and .bash_profile is fine.  Very puzzling why it won't pick up this simple path to this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a little package.json magic in addition to the shebang it seems like so:

```
"bin": {
    "cli-project": "index.js"
  },
```

Then do `npm link .` in the application directory. Works!